# Migrating .net framework to .netcore 3.1 (Servicestack.Razor Views)

Tags: model-view-controller, razor, view, servicestack, viewpage

I'm migrating a .net framework web to .netcore

Having issues with moving the 'Views' folder. It seems that every razor page with
`@inherits ViewPage<TModel>`

I get an error `"The type or namespace 'ViewPage<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).`

I've installed ServiceStack.Razor and ServiceStack.Mvc nuget package in my project but it's not able to recognize it in Views folder.

On my _ViewImports.cshtml, I have also added @using package references

Also, I am using 'Request.[]' from ServiceStack.Razor but it's unable to recognize Request.

Any ideas of what I'm missing? Should I be updating it to @model instead? When I update to @model it's working fine but 'Request' is still unrecognized

Answer (score 0):

Unlike most features in ServiceStack which could be ported and multi-targeted to support both .NET Framework and .NET Core, ServiceStack.Razor's coupling to System.Web [could not support .NET Core](https://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#servicestack-features-that-wont-be-supported-in-net-core).

Instead [ServiceStack.Razor for .NET Core](https://docs.servicestack.net/netcore-razor) was rewritten to work on top of ASP.NET Core MVC which is only contained in the **ServiceStack.Mvc** package not the the .NET Framework only **ServiceStack.Razor** package (which shouldn't be referenced in .NET Core).

Most of the syntax remained the same so porting should still require a small amount of effort as seen in ServiceStack.Razor's Razor Rockstars .NET Core port vs the original .NET Framework:

- [Razor Rockstars .NET Core](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/RazorRockstars)
- [Razor Rockstars for .NET Framework](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/RazorRockstars)

But given that it's a rewrite that works on top of ASP.NET Core MVC I wouldn't try to convert your existing ServiceStack.Razor project but instead to **start with an empty new [razor](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/razor) project so it starts from a well-known working configuration** and then copying your existing Razor Views and Services across to the new project.

You can create a razor project via either the command-line:

```
$ x new razor ProjectName
```

Or using ServiceStack's online project template creator at: https://servicestack.net/start